# How can I handle saving dates only while accounting for time zones?

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, timezone

I'm trying to create a system that allows a user to schedule an event for a certain date.

On the server end, I have a SQL job that runs at 3:00 AM EST every day.

On the client end, the user is selecting a date in a datepicker.

I need to ensure that the SQL job can look at the date the user saves and execute an action on whatever day that is in the users timezone.

I've tried storing the following (rough C# pseudocode):

```
DateTime scheduledDateUtc = ConvertToUTC(dateEnteredByUser.Date, usersTimezone).Date;
```

I then execute the event based on the following comparison in the SQL job:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, scheduled_date_utc) = CONVERT(DATE, GETUTCDATE())
```

This is failing on some edge cases and definitely wrong, but I don't know what the right strategy is.

Additionally, it's not clear to me how I ought to write unit tests for these edge cases.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to worry about timezones.  The computer local timezone setting will automatically adjust.  The DateTime object is saved in UTC time on every computer automatically and transferred between PC and database in UTC time (provided you don't use strings).  So no conversion is required.

Comment: What does "failing" mean?   What error does your current code generate?

Comment: @jdweng It depends on his column type in SQL. `DateTime` and `DateTime2` do not have time zone information while `DateTimeOffset` does. The user input should be [converted to UTC first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) when using a `DateTime` column.

Comment: Save it as `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: Some clarification: the value I get from the datepicker on the client has no timezone information associated, and I only care about the date, not the time.

So client will give me something like `2017-09-13 00:00:001`.

Failing means sometimes the job executes the event one day early or one day late, relative to the user's timezone.

Comment: it is being stored as a `DateTime` column, right?

Comment: @Jake_ Correct.

Comment: Timezone is not part of a DateTime object.  Dates are stored in UTC as a number.  As I said the timezone is only used to convert a string Date to a number Date.  DO NOT CONVERT!!!  The Net parse function automatically does the conversion based on the PC Timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to convert to UTC? Instead of manually converting to UTC I would try setting it like so

`DateTime scheduledDateUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateEnteredByUser.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Comment: This might cause issues if a user is near a more extreme timezone; i.e. UTC+12 or UTC-11.